# Swift how to set cache tag value in UITableView for multiple sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, caching

I am new to Swift. I am trying to show images in my tableview. I am following this [tutorial](http://sweettutos.com/2015/12/31/swift-how-to-asynchronously-download-and-cache-images-without-relying-on-third-party-libraries/).

In my `UITableView`, as shown in this [tutorial](http://sweettutos.com/2015/12/31/swift-how-to-asynchronously-download-and-cache-images-without-relying-on-third-party-libraries/). I am storing images in cache. This works fine if tableview has only one section. How should I set the `forKey` value if I have multiple sections in my tableview?
How to set this value `self.cache.setObject(image!, forKey:indexPath.row)` according to section and row? Thanks!!

This is my code for `UITableView`

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    if(tableView == tableview){
        return categoryArray.count
    }else{
        return 1
    }
}

func tableView(tableView : UITableView,  titleForHeaderInSection section: Int)->String
{
    if(tableView == tableview){
        return categoryArray.objectAtIndex(section) as! String
    }else{
        return ""
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if(tableView == tableview){
        print("Count = \(myList[section].count)")
        return myList[section].count
    }
    else{
        return 5
    }

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if(tableView == tableview) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomEventCell

cell.cellBackgroundImg.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")


        if (self.cache.objectForKey(indexPath.row) != nil){
            print("Cached image used, no need to download it")
            cell.cellBackgroundImg?.image = self.cache.objectForKey(indexPath.row) as? UIImage
        }else{

            let img_url = myList[indexPath.section].objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("image") as? String

            if img_url != nil{
                print("Load the image from URL")
                let url = NSURL(string: img_url!)!
                let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
                let defaultSession = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
                let task = defaultSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        cell.cellBackgroundImg?.image = image
                        self.cache.setObject(image!, forKey:indexPath.row)
                    })
                })
                task.resume()

            }
        }
        return cell
      }   
    }
```

Comment: Try to use `tag` - (An integer that you can use to identify view objects in your application.) instead of `indexPath.row`

Comment: @Rahul Sorry could you please elaborate your comment please

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the URL string as the key for the cache?. That way the cache will be valid if the same image is used in multiple rows, multiple sections or the number of rows changes

Comment: Why not use img_url as the key for the image in the dictionary.  This way you can get the img_url from myList and then see if image exists in cache for that url.  Then you won't need to worry about rows and sections

Comment: @Paulw11 Yeah thanks for the idea. I will use the URL string. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tag` also. Here is the code which uses tag value. Also you may be need to consider error handling in your code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    if(tableView == tableview) {
        let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomEventCell

      customCell.eventTitle.text = title
        customCell.cellBackgroundImg.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
        // calculate tagValue and set it to cache objectForKey
       // here I have taken big numbers so same number will not repeat 
        let tagValue = (indexPath.section * 100) + indexPath.row + 200

        if (self.cache.objectForKey(tagValue) != nil){
            print("Cached image used, no need to download it")
            customCell.cellBackgroundImg?.image = self.cache.objectForKey(tagValue) as? UIImage
        }else{

            let img_url = myList[indexPath.section].objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("image") as? String

            if img_url != nil{
                print("Load the image from URL")
                let url = NSURL(string: img_url!)!
                let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
                let defaultSession = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
                let task = defaultSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) in

                    if error != nil {
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }else if(data != nil){
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                            customCell.cellBackgroundImg?.image = image
                            self.cache.setObject(image!, forKey:tagValue)
                        })
                    }else {
                        print("Error : Image data is nil")
                    }
                })
                task.resume()
            }
            else {
                print("Error : Image URL is nil")
            }

        }
       cell = customCell
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The author of the tutorial seems to have made a mistake in choosing to use `indexPath.row` as the key for their cache.  A row number has a very tenuous link to the image; the thing that identifies the image is its URL.  By using the row, there will be problems where:

- Row numbers change (incorrect cache hits)
- There are multiple sections (just general ickyness as you have found)
- The same image is used in multiple rows (unnecessary cache misses).

You can easily modify `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to use the URL as the cache key:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    if(tableView == tableview) {
        let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomEventCell
        customCell.cellBackgroundImg.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")

        if let img_url = myList[indexPath.section].objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("image") as? String {

            if let image = self.cache.objectForKey(img_url) as? UIImage {
                print("Cached image used, no need to download it")
                cell.cellBackgroundImg?.image = image
            } else {
                print("Load the image from URL")
                if let url = NSURL(string: img_url)
                    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
                    let defaultSession = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
                    let task = defaultSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) in

                        guard let downloadData= data && error == nil else {
                            print("error downloading image:\(error)"
                            return
                         }
                         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                             if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                                 customCell.cellBackgroundImg?.image = image
                                 self.cache.setObject(image, forKey:img_url)
                             }  
                          })
                    })
                    task.resume()
                }
           }
        }
        cell = customCell
    }
    return cell  
}
```

Your code also wasn't very defensive.  There was a lot of force-unwrapping which will give you an exception if the data isn't right

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are caching all images using the `row` reference, but if your `UITableView` has more than one section it will have repeated row values. For example:

Section 0 > row 0, row 1, row 2
Section 1 > row 0, row 1
Section 2 > row 0

All sections has "row 0".

To fix it you have to do:

1) Create formatted keys like "SECTION-ROW", for example:

```
self.cache.setObject(image!, forKey:"\(indexPath.section)-\(indexPath.row")))
self.cache.objectForKey(indexPath.row)
```

2) Just use libs like: https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift